# Getting an "ambiguous redirect" error

Tags: bash

The following line in my Bash script

```
 echo $AAAA"     "$DDDD"         "$MOL_TAG  >>  ${OUPUT_RESULTS}
```

gives me this error:

```
 line 46: ${OUPUT_RESULTS}: ambiguous redirect
```

Why?

Comment: you are not showing all. where did you get `${OUPUT_RESULTS}`. Its also a spelling error if you meant `$OUTPUT_RESULTS}`

Comment: if one wrote `OUPUT_RESULTS = "filename.log"` one will get ambiguous redirect. Because bash wants NO SPACE around the `=` operator.

Comment: `OUPUT_RESULTS` likely contained space (eg `toto tata.txt`) in its value...

Answer (score 361, accepted):

Bash can be pretty obtuse sometimes.

The following commands all return different error messages for basically the same error:

```
$ echo hello >
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline`

$ echo hello > ${NONEXISTENT}
bash: ${NONEXISTENT}: ambiguous redirect

$ echo hello > "${NONEXISTENT}"
bash: : No such file or directory
```

Adding quotes around the variable seems to be a good way to deal with the "ambiguous redirect" message: You tend to get a better message when you've made a typing mistake -- and **when the error is due to spaces in the filename, using quotes is the fix.**

Comment: You'll also get this if you redirect the output of a script that contains redirects. Don't ask me how I know this.

Comment: @PaulJackson, ...that's not true. As a copy-and-pasteable demonstrator: `sh -c 'echo hello >/tmp/hello' >/tmp/world` works properly.

Comment: Perhaps a valuable addition, for me using sh instead of bash was a solution.

This:

    for f in onfw/*; do xslt -xsl:dwsToTEI.xslt -s:- < "$f" > data/`basename "$f"`; done

works in sh, bash gives a ambiguous redirect for filenames with spaces (quoting did not help)

Answer (score 33):

Do you have a variable named `OUPUT_RESULTS` or is it the more likely `OUTPUT_RESULTS`?

---

```
michael@isolde:~/junk$ ABC=junk.txt
michael@isolde:~/junk$ echo "Booger" > $ABC
michael@isolde:~/junk$ echo "Booger" >> $ABB
bash: $ABB: ambiguous redirect
michael@isolde:~/junk$
```

Comment: If your `ABC="junk file.txt"`, this would still have the problem.

Comment: This answer led me to my solution, too.  I defined a variable as `INPUT` but was using it as `Input`.  Case-sensitivity for the win!

Answer (score 20):

put quotes around your variable. If it happens to have spaces, it will give you "ambiguous redirect" as well. also check your spelling

```
echo $AAAA"     "$DDDD"         "$MOL_TAG  >>  "${OUPUT_RESULTS}"
```

eg of ambiguous redirect

```
$ var="file with spaces"
$ echo $AAAA"     "$DDDD"         "$MOL_TAG >> ${var}
bash: ${var}: ambiguous redirect
$ echo $AAAA"     "$DDDD"         "$MOL_TAG >> "${var}"
$ cat file\ with\ spaces
aaaa     dddd         mol_tag
```

Comment: Quotes don't matter.  If there are spaces in the variable expansion you'll just get things going to the wrong file and/or spurious error messages involving the post-space portion of the file name.

Comment: @JUSTMYcorrectOPINION, the shell doesn't re-parse after parameter expansions -- meaning that contents after the space within expansion results can't result in a different piece of syntax being filled in.

Answer (score 7):

I've recently found that blanks in the name of the redirect file will cause the "ambiguous redirect" message.

For example if you redirect to `application$(date +%Y%m%d%k%M%S).log` and you specify the wrong formatting characters, the redirect will fail before 10 AM for example. If however, you used `application$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).log` it would succeed. This is because the `%k` format yields `' 9'` for 9AM where `%H` yields `'09'` for 9AM.

`echo $(date +%Y%m%d%k%M%S)` gives `20140626 95138`

`echo $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)` gives `20140626095138`

The erroneous date might give something like:

```
echo "a" > myapp20140626 95138.log
```

where the following is what would be desired:

```
echo "a" > myapp20140626095138.log
```

Comment: The error is that you should have quotes around the variable, regardless of whether it contains spaces. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 6):

Does the path specified in ${OUPUT_RESULTS} contain any whitespace characters? If so, you may want to consider using `... >> "${OUPUT_RESULTS}"` (using quotes).

(You may  also want to consider renaming your variable to `${OUTPUT_RESULTS}`)

Answer (score 4):

If you are here trying to debug this "ambiguous redirect" error with GitHub Actions. I highly suggest trying it this way:

`echo "MY_VAR=foobar" >> $GITHUB_ENV`

The behavior I experienced with $GITHUB_ENV is that, it adds it to the pipeline environment variables as my example shows `MY_VAR`

Comment: Weird I found this immediately after reading the answer on how to set env vars in bash via GitHub Actions. Thanks for this!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70564328/github-actions-for-multiple-environment-variable-setup-with-automation

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when trying to use brace expansion to write output to multiple files.

for example: `echo "text" > {f1,f2}.txt` results in `-bash: {f1,f2}.txt: ambiguous redirect`

In this case, use `tee` to output to multiple files:

```
echo "text" | tee {f1,f2,...,fn}.txt 1>/dev/null
```

the `1>/dev/null` will prevent the text from being written to **stdout**

If you want to append to the file(s) use `tee -a`

Answer (score 2):

If your script's redirect contains a variable, and the script body defines that variable in a section enclosed by parenthesis, you will get the "ambiguous redirect" error. Here's a reproducible example:

1. `vim a.sh` to create the script
2. edit script to contain `(logit="/home/ubuntu/test.log" && echo "a") >> ${logit}`
3. `chmod +x a.sh` to make it executable
4. `a.sh`

If you do this, you will get "/home/ubuntu/a.sh: line 1: $logit: ambiguous redirect". This is because

> "Placing a list of commands between parentheses causes a subshell to
>   be created, and each of the commands in list to be executed in that
>   subshell, without removing non-exported variables. Since the list is
>   executed in a subshell, variable assignments do not remain in effect
>   after the subshell completes."

From [Using parenthesis to group and expand expressions](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-brackets.html)

To correct this, you can modify the script in step 2 to define the variable outside the parenthesis: `logit="/home/ubuntu/test.log" && (echo "a") >> $logit`

Answer (score 1):

One other thing that can cause "ambiguous redirect" is `\t` `\n` `\r` in the variable name you are writing too

Maybe not `\n\r`? But err on the side of caution

Try this

```
echo "a" > ${output_name//[$'\t\n\r']}
```

I got hit with this one while parsing HTML, Tabs `\t` at the beginning of the line.

Comment: The error is not quoting the variable. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 1):

I just had this error in a bash script. The issue was an accidental \ at the end of the previous line that was giving an error.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the case too.

you have not specified the file in a variable and redirecting output to it, then bash will throw this error.

```
files=`ls`
out_file = /path/to/output_file.t
for i in `echo "$files"`;
do
    content=`cat $i` 
    echo "${content}  ${i}" >> ${out_file}
done
```

**out_file** variable is not set up correctly so keep an eye on this too. 
BTW this code is printing all the content and its filename on the console.

Comment: In my case I was using 
 - 
for i in "/path/to/files/*";
 - 
I had to remove the doublequotes.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this was a helpful warning, because the target variable (not the file) was misspelled and did not exist.

```
echo "ja" >> $doesNotExist
```

resulting in

```
./howdy.sh: line 4: $doesNotExist: ambiguous redirect
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a variable name in the shell command, you must concatenate it with `+` sign.

for example :

if you have two files, and you are not going to hard code the file name, instead you want to use the variable name 
`"input.txt" = x` 
`"output.txt" = y`

> then ('shell command within quotes' + x > + y)

it will work this way especially if you are using this inside a python program with os.system command probably

Answer (score 0):

For my case, if I specify the output file via a env (e.g `$ENV_OF_LOG_FILE`), then will get the error **ambiguous redirect**.

But, if I use plain text as file path (e.g `/path/to/log_file`), then there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on a previous answer: I had copy/pasted a command into a crontab file and somehow ended up with some non-printable characters on the end which messed up my filename.