# Cleanup Script Error - BASH

Tags: bash, shell, logging

**My cleanup script that logs what i deleted.**

```
log=$HOME/Deleted/$(date)
find $HOME/OldLogFiles/ -type f -mtime -7 -exec ls -latr {} \; -exec echo was deleted on `date` \; -exec rm -f "{}" \;|paste - - >> $log
```

I keep getting these errors however...

```
./test.sh: line 3: $log: ambiguous redirect
find: ‘ls’ terminated by signal 13
find: ‘ls’ terminated by signal 13
```

Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `-exec ls -latr "{}"` ?

Comment: I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the "ambigous redirect" is because the `log` variable contains spaces. You need to add quotes around it (`"$log"`). Check out [Getting an "ambiguous redirect" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462385/bash-ambiguous-redirect). This causes the `paste` command to finish early, closing the pipe that ls writes to, which in turn leads to the `‘ls’ terminated by signal 13` errors.

That said, you might want to use a custom date format in the date command (maybe `date -I`?). Check out the man page for date.