# Confused with my "ambiguous redirect"

Tags: bash, shell

I keep getting ambiguous redirect in bash script.

I'm new, so if someone could explain why I'm getting this with my following code, that would be great.

Here's my code!

```
$input = [user inputs an email]
$variable=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")
$mem_list=/root/Desktop/Dan/Logs/member-name-file" "$variable.txt
```

Here's the code that's getting ambiguous (there's a couple of these, but same problem.

```
if [[ -f $mem_list ]]          #check if file exists already
then
    echo $input >> $mem_list   #if file is already there, just append input to the file
else 
    echo $input > $mem_list    #if file is not found, make a new one [Error is here!!]
fi
```

Help me kindly, thanks!

Comment: Also see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462385/getting-an-ambiguous-redirect-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $mem_list contains a space, you have to quote it; e.g.

```
if [[ -f "$mem_list" ]]
    echo $input >> "$mem_list"
```

Comment: You should also put `"$input"` in double quotes, and generally any variable interpolation where word splitting and wildcard expansion is not specifically what you require.

Comment: ack; the whole `echo` is bad for giving out user input because it does not support the `--` delimiter (--> try to give out 'input=-e').  Writing `printf "%s" "$input" >> "$mem_list"` would be more reliable.

Comment: the funny thing, and my main question, is that it works with >> but not with > (without quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Your variable assignments are wrong too. The lvalue has no `$` sign and there must not be spaces around `=`.

```
mem_list="/root/Desktop/Dan/Logs/member-name-file $variable.txt"
```

What do you mean with `[user inputs an email]`? My bash 4.2 is a bit baffled...

Comment: by [user inputs an email], I meant that in my whole program, user inputs email, one by one, which gets saved onto a textfile