# Redirect to a file which is got from command line

Tags: shell

I'm a beginner. :)
I'm trying to ask the name of file from prompt in a shell
and edit that file in another shell like this:

`test.sh`

```
echo "enter file name"
read word
sh test2.sh
```

`test2.sh`

```
read number
echo "$number" >> $word
```

I get an error

```
Test2.sh: line 1: $mAmbiguous redirect
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting an "ambiguous redirect" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462385/getting-an-ambiguous-redirect-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a variable from `test.sh` to be visible to its child processes, you need to `export` it.  In your case, you would seem to want to `export word`.  Perhaps a better approach would be for `test2.sh` to accept the destination file as a parameter instead, though.

test.sh

```
echo "enter file name"
read word
test2.sh "$word"
```

test2.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
: ${1?must have destination file name}  # fail if missing
read number
echo "$number" >> "$1"
```

Comment: You need to have it in your `PATH`,  or use `./test2.sh`.  Obviously, the file needs to have execute permission (`chmod +x ./test2.sh`).