# Program tester, bash

Tags: c, bash, ambiguous, runner

I'm trying to test a program (tp3) with several input files and printing the output in another file. So I've designed the following bash script name runner to do everything at the same time:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm $2
clear
FILES=(`ls ${1}`)
cmd='./tp3'
for f in ${FILES[*]}
do
    echo "$f"
    echo "--------------<$f>--------------" >> $2
    $cmd < $1$f 2>> $2 >> $2
done
```

Everytime I run this script I get the following error:

```
./runner: line 10: $2: ambiguous redirect
./runner: line 11: testtest: No such file or directory
```

To run the bash script I do:

```
./runner test
```

What is wrong in the script?

Modifications to make it work:
First of all I've quoted the variables, then I've replaced the second argument "$2" for a file named "TEST" and now everything is working just fine.

New code:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm TEST
clear
FILES=(`ls *.in`)
cmd='./tp3'
for f in ${FILES[*]}
do
    echo "$f"
    echo "--------------<"$f">--------------" >> "TEST"
    "$cmd" < "$1$f" >> "TEST" 2>> "TEST"
done
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Try `$cmd < $1$f >> $2 2>&1`. Although that won't fix it, it's better practice. Your problem is that `$2` doesn't exist. You're only supplying one argument... By the way, storing commands in a variable is bad practice, as is looping over files using that kind of for loop construction. You're better of using `find` but that's just an FYI.

Comment: Quote your variables! That will also get you [better error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462385/getting-an-ambiguous-redirect-error). I suspect `$1$f` should be `"$1/$f"`, and put `"$2"` instead of `$2` everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running `./runner test` in which `test` is `$1` and `$2` is empty. Your redirection is therefor illegal. Also try to couple stdout and stderr when pointing to the same output. This can be done as follows: `command arguments > output 2>&1`. This will send stderr output to where ever the stdout output is sent.

Also, as Wintermute pointed out: quote variables. Spaces in variables will make it be interpreted as separate arguments. e.g. `command $1` supplies two arguments to `command` if `$1` equals `some string` for example.

This translates into the following: you use `$f` if this contains a space it will split the argument and everything after the space will be treated as extra arguments or commands rather than one single argument.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and advices. I was able to make it work. :-)

Comment: My pleasure, don't forget to accept the answer and vote if you deemed it a quality answer.