# Ambiguous redirect error while using rtmpdump

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, rtmp

So I was trying to download somevideos using rtmpdump, and I used [this](https://github.com/christopher-beckham/cs109-dl-videos/blob/master/get.sh) shell script which is supposed to download the some videos but it gave me and error message saying

> ./script: line 9: $1: ambiguous redirect

Now I am pretty sure that I am doing something silly so I will tell you exactly what I did. I first downloaded that above file into my system saved it as "script". And opened terminal and typed:

> ./script

and it gave me the above error.

Now I have also gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462385/getting-an-ambiguous-redirect-error) thread, and also some other threads but they don't seem help me at all and now I have nowhere to go. please save me.

Comment: from the original URL USAGE: `./get.sh hq-urls.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`script` tries to use `$1` as the name of a file for redirection (e.g., `someCommand > "$1"`), but you didn't supply a an argument when you called `script`.

Comment: `./script firstArgument`.

Answer (score 0):

The script needs a file as the first parameter which will have one video to download per line