# Creating Bash Script Filenames Based on C++ Binary Runtime Parameters

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a bash shell script that calls a C++ binary. I would like the output of the binary to be saved to a file, with a name based on run-time parameters that were used to call the binary.

```
#!/bin/bash
c_command="./code -v 1 -i file.txt -o out.txt -a 3 -w"
output=$($c_command)
echo output > ${c_command}_output.txt
```

Unfortunately, this is resulting in the following error:

```
./script.sh: line 4: ${c_command}_output.txt: ambiguous redirect
```

I was inspired by this stack exchange [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/855461/bash-for-loop-redirect-output-to-variable-filename), but clearly, something is not right.

Comment: There are bigger problems with this code. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: However, the **immediate** issue is caused by the lack of quotes.

Comment: Making it `>"${c_command}_output.txt"` would fix that syntax error, but do you really want to make a file named `code -v 1 -i file.txt -o out.txt -a 3 -w_output.txt`?

Comment: And `echo output` is writing the string "output". It's not writing the content of the variable named `output`.

Comment: Immediately, though, this is just too broad to be answerable -- you've got at least four separate bugs; there's not just one question here.

Comment: ...the issue you asked about most immediately is a duplicate of [getting an ambiguous redirect error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462385/getting-an-ambiguous-redirect-error).