# GitHub Actions for multiple environment variable setup with Automation

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, amazon-ecr

I am working with GitHub to deploy a container-based application on multiple environments, I have two environments:

1. Dev
2. Prod

I am building the application on both Environments, this is my yml file:

```
name: 'Manual - Build & Deploy - Enterprise'

on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - '**'

  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      git-ref:
        description: Git Ref (Optional)
        default: develop
        required: false

      account:
        description: slb-dev, slb-prod
        default: slb-dev
        required: true
        
      account_prod:
       description: slb-dev, slb-prod
       default: slb-prod
       required: true

      environment:
        description: development (main, int, qs), production (v1_demo, v1_rosecity, demo)
        default: main
        required: false

      microservice:
        description: chroma, liquid, tenant, dashboard, lims, lims-simulator, client, logging, metrc
        default: chroma
        required: false

      builddir:
        description: MicroChromatographyService/MicroChromatographyService, MicroLiquidHandlingService/MicroLiquidHandlingService, MicroTenantService/MicroTenantService, MicroDashboardService/MicroDashboardService, LIMSIntegrationService/LIMSIntegrationService, LIMSSimulatorService/LIMSSimulatorService, IntegrationHubClientService/IntegrationHubClientService, PerkinElmer.LoggingService/PerkinElmer.LoggingService, MetRCReportService/MetRCReportService
        default: MicroChromatographyService/MicroChromatographyService
        required: false

jobs:
  setup:
    name: Setup ENV Variables
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
     name: Production
     url: https://dev.test.com
    steps:

    - name: Set Vars
      id: setvars
      run: |
          echo "::set-output name=APP_NAME::${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
          echo "::set-output name=AWS_REGION::us-east-1"
          echo "::set-output name=SHA8::${{ github.sha }} | cut -c1-8)"
          echo "::set-output name=BUILD_DIR::${{ github.event.inputs.builddir }}"
          echo "::set-output name=ECR_REPOSITORY::${{ github.event.inputs.account }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
          echo "::set-output name=ECS_CLUSTER::${{ github.event.inputs.account }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}"
          echo "::set-output name=ECS_SERVICE::${{ github.event.inputs.account }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
          echo "::set-output name=ECS_TASK_DEFINITION::${{ github.event.inputs.account }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
          echo "::set-output name=ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE::task-definition-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}.json"
          echo "::set-output name=ECS_CONTAINER_NAME::${{ github.event.inputs.account }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"

    outputs:
      APP_NAME: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.APP_NAME }}
      AWS_REGION: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.AWS_REGION }}
      SHA8: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.SHA8 }}
      BUILD_DIR: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.BUILD_DIR }}
      ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
      ECS_CLUSTER: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_CLUSTER }}
      ECS_SERVICE: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_SERVICE }}
      ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }}
      ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}
      ECS_CONTAINER_NAME: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_CONTAINER_NAME }}
      
  setup2:
    name: Setup prod ENV Variables
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: dev
      url: https://production.test.com
    steps:
      
    - name: Set Vars
      id: setprodvars
      run: |
          echo "::set-output name=APP_NAME::${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
          echo "::set-output name=AWS_REGION::us-east-1"
          echo "::set-output name=SHA8::${{ github.sha }} | cut -c1-8)"
          echo "::set-output name=BUILD_DIR::${{ github.event.inputs.builddir }}"
          echo "::set-output name=ECR_REPOSITORY::${{ github.event.inputs.account_prod }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
          echo "::set-output name=ECS_CLUSTER::${{ github.event.inputs.account_prod }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}"
          echo "::set-output name=ECS_SERVICE::${{ github.event.inputs.account_prod }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
          echo "::set-output name=ECS_TASK_DEFINITION::${{ github.event.inputs.account_prod }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
          echo "::set-output name=ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE::task-definition-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}.json"
          echo "::set-output name=ECS_CONTAINER_NAME::${{ github.event.inputs.account_prod }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
    outputs:
      APP_NAME: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.APP_NAME }}
      AWS_REGION: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.AWS_REGION }}
      SHA8: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.SHA8 }}
      BUILD_DIR: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.BUILD_DIR }}
      ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
      ECS_CLUSTER: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_CLUSTER }}
      ECS_SERVICE: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_SERVICE }}
      ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }}
      ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}
      ECS_CONTAINER_NAME: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_CONTAINER_NAME }}


      
  DeployDev:
    name: Deploy to Dev 
    needs: setup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
     packages: write
     contents: write
     id-token: write
    environment: 
      name: Dev
      url: 'http://dev.myapp.com'
    steps:
    - name: Set Environments
      run: |
        if [[ "${{github.event.inputs.account}}" == "slb-dev" ]]; then
          echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        fi

        if [[ "${{github.event.inputs.account}}" == "slb-prod" ]]; then
          echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        fi

    - name: Clone Repository (Current branch)
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      if: github.event.inputs.git-ref == ''

    - name: Clone Repository (Custom Ref)
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      if: github.event.inputs.git-ref != ''
      with:
        ref: ${{ github.event.inputs.git-ref }}

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}         
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }} 
        aws-region: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.AWS_REGION }}

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      id: build-image
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
      run: |
        cd ${{ needs.setup.outputs.BUILD_DIR }}
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest
        echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"

    - name: Download task definition
      run: |
        aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }} --query taskDefinition > ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}

    - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
      id: task-def
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
      with:
        task-definition: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}
        container-name: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_CONTAINER_NAME }}
        image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

    - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
      with:
        task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
        service: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_SERVICE }}
        cluster: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_CLUSTER }}
        wait-for-service-stability: true


  DeployProd:
    name: Deploy to Production 
    needs: [setup2, DeployDev]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
     packages: write
     contents: write
     id-token: write
    environment: 
      name: Production
      url: 'http://dev.myapp.com'
    steps:
    - name: Set Environments
      run: |
        if [[ "${{github.event.inputs.account_prod}}" == "slb-dev" ]]; then
          echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        fi
        if [[ "${{github.event.inputs.account_prod}}" == "slb-prod" ]]; then
          echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        fi
    - name: Clone Repository (Current branch)
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      if: github.event.inputs.git-ref == ''

    - name: Clone Repository (Custom Ref)
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      if: github.event.inputs.git-ref != ''
      with:
        ref: ${{ github.event.inputs.git-ref }}

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}         
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }} 
        aws-region: ${{ needs.setup2.outputs.AWS_REGION }}

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      id: build-image
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
      run: |
        cd ${{ needs.setup.outputs.BUILD_DIR }}
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest
        echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"
    - name: Download task definition
      run: |
        aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }} --query taskDefinition > ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}
    - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
      id: task-def
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
      with:
        task-definition: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}
        container-name: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_CONTAINER_NAME }}
        image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

    - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
      with:
        task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
        service: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_SERVICE }}
        cluster: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_CLUSTER }}
        wait-for-service-stability: true
```

As you can see, we are just duplicating the env variables, but what we want is essentially get rid of that step and do it using a single step for the inputs which we have, then things should go automatically from dev to prod, I think something based on an if condition can be done, but I am just not sure how to implement it any ideas are welcome, thanks.

Comment: An option could be to use a [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows#limitations). Did you try using one?

Comment: It is an interesting concept, I wonder how I could implement it for my workflow, if you could nudge me in that direction, that would be great.

Comment: I am not even 100% sure if that will work since we have different inputs for different workflows, and so even if we use a reusable workflow, the inputs need to be looped in.

Comment: Basically, you could create a **generic/reusable workflow** that would gather the common steps between your `DeployDev` and `DeployProd` jobs. Then, each of those jobs in your current workflow would call this generic workflow **with specific inputs** according to the environment. Here is a basic example using this concept: [reusable workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/33-reusable-workflow.yml) and [workflow call](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/34-workflow-call.yml)

Comment: Anything that's not a secret you could have in a file within repo, then you just source that file. As for secrets, you can have them per environment https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#environment-secrets